# Pagination not working in some author pages

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I have an author archive page to display authors' posts. In some of the authors the pagination works, but in some cases it doesn't.

Where is the problem? Here is my code:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$wpfp_before = "";
echo "<div class='wpfp-span'>";

if ($wpfp_before):
echo '<div class="wpfp-page-before">'.$wpfp_before.'</div>';
endif;
$favorite_post_ids = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wpfp_favorites', true);
if ($favorite_post_ids) {
$favorite_post_ids = array_reverse($favorite_post_ids);
$post_per_page = wpfp_get_option("post_per_page");
$page = intval(get_query_var('paged'));

$qry = new wp_query(array('post_type' => 'videosprogram' ,  'post__in' => $favorite_post_ids ,'posts_per_page' => 3,'paged' => $paged ) );                      

while ($qry->have_posts() ) : $qry->the_post();


//Loop ....


endwhile; wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $qry ) ); ?>
```

UPDATE:-

i try this way :-

```
function cpt_on_author_page( $query ) {
    $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
    //$author_name = get_post_meta($curauth->id, 'author_name', true);
    if ( $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'videosprogram' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
        $query->set( 'meta_key' , 'show_program_editors');
        $query->set( 'meta_value' , $curauth->id); 


    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cpt_on_author_page' );
```

but not show me any post

Comment: Why aren't you using the main query? Where are you using this code? Please have a look at `pre_get_posts` and `WP_Query`. Your custom query just seems all wrong.

Comment: no wrong in my wp_query, its get me all post but the problem is when go to page NO 2 its show me page not found

Comment: if the *main query* has no posts, then you will get a 404 regardless of the results of your query in the template. that's why you should use `pre_get_posts` instead.

Comment: @Milo How can use main query ,,, can you edit my query ?